# File upload progress bar interferes with Controller redirect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a file submission form and a progress bar tracking how far along the upload is. However the javascript controlling the progress bar interferes with my controller and I'm not sure how to fix it. My controller never redirects back home with the link (it works without the progress bar implemented). Removing `window.location.href="/";` does not fix this issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**home.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{route('file.store')}}" method="post" class="w-100" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="progress" id="progressBar">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="custom-file overflow-hidden rounded-pill mb-3">
        <input id=“file type="file" class="custom-file-input rounded-pill" name="file">
        <label id="fileName" for=“file” class="custom-file-label rounded-pill">Choose file</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="file-upload btn btn-primary btn-block rounded-pill shadow mb-3" id="uploadButton">
</form>
```

**FileController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // Process the file
    $link = “https://example.com”;
    session()->flash("link",$link);
    // return back to home with link to download the file
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("progressBar").style.display = "none";
            var bar = $('.bar');
            var percent = $('.percent');
            $('form').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function() {
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                    document.getElementById("progressBar").style.display = "";
                    document.getElementById('uploadButton').disabled = true;
                },
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    document.getElementById("progressBar").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('uploadButton').disabled = false;
                    window.location.href="/";
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: progress bar is lot easier using vue.js

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
public function uploadMultipleFile(Request $request)
    {
 
         foreach($request->file('file') as $image)
         {
              $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
              $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
              Gallery::insert(['title' => $new_name]);
         }
 
         $res = array(
          'success'  => 'Multiple Image File Has Been uploaded Successfully'
         );
 
        return response()->json($res);
    }

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend:function(){
$('#success').empty();
$('.progress-bar').text('0%');
$('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
},
uploadProgress:function(event, position, total, percentComplete){
$('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '0%');
$('.progress-bar').css('width', percentComplete + '0%');
},
success:function(data)
{
if(data.success)
{
$('#success').html('<div class="text-success text-center"><b>'+data.success+'</b></div><br /><br />');
$('#success').append(data.image);
$('.progress-bar').text('Uploaded');
$('.progress-bar').css('width', '100%');
}
}
});
});
</script>
```